# how to find the biggest multiplication between numbers in a given array(limit is 100000 numbers)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multiplication

I am trying to learn programming and in our school we have exercises which are automatically checked by a bot. The time limit is 1 second and the memory limit is 1024 mb.
I've tried sorting the array in an ascending order and then multiplicating the 2 highest numbers but that was too slow(my sorting algorithm could be slow so if possible suggest a sorting algorithm.)
This is the fastest way that I've been able to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int Maksimumas(int n, int X[]);
ofstream fr("U1rez.txt");
ifstream fd("U1.txt");
int main()
{
    int n, A[100000], B[100000], maxi=0;
    fd >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fd >> A[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            B[j] = A[i] * A[j];
        }
        maxi = Maksimumas(n, B);
        A[i] = B[maxi];
    }
    maxi = Maksimumas(n, A);
    fr << A[maxi];
    fr.close();
    return 0;
}
int Maksimumas(int n, int X[])
{
    int maxi = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (X[maxi] < X[i]) {
            maxi = i;
        }
    }
    return maxi;
}
```

n is the size of the array for anyone wondering.

Comment: If you want to find the maximum and the second maximum number, do you really need to sort the entire array?

Comment: Try using std::nth_element.

Comment: or [std::partial_sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort)

Comment: What else do you suggest? The current fastest method that I've come up with( which is still too slow, needs to be about 4 times faster). This method doesn't sort the array in any way, it just uses the array for multiplication and puts the multiplication answer into a 2nd array. I really need help to optimize my code for this problem. I want to get better at programming.

Comment: sorting is `O(N * logN)` while to find the max and second max number a single pass through the array is necessary only.

Comment: How would you suggest finding the 2nd max assuming that it could be the same number? I don't know how to solve a problem like that

Comment: I mean, when you find a new max, what could you do with the old max?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to sort the entire array - you just need the two largest positive numbers and the two smallest negative numbers. Everything in between is inconsequential.

Instead, you can go over all the input and keep track of the two largest positive numbers and two smallest negative numbers.; At the end of the iteration, multiply each pair (if found), and compare the results.

```cpp
// fd is opened like the original question, n is the number of elements to read
// that part is omitted for brevity

int max = -1; 
int preMax = -1;
int min = 1;
int preMin = 1;

int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fd >> temp;
    if (temp > preMax) {
        if (temp > max) {
            preMax = max;
            max = temp;
        } else {
            preMax = temp;
        }
    } else if (temp < preMin) {
        if (temp < min) {
            preMin = min;
            min = temp;
        } else {
            preMin = temp;
        }
    }
}

int result = -1;
if (preMax >= 0) {
    result = preMax * max;
}
if (preMin <= 0) {
    int tempResult = preMin * min;
    if (tempResult > result) {
        result = tempResult;
    }
}

return result;
```

Comment: are you finding both the maxes and the minimums while putting the numbers into the array?

Comment: @emirisu no, I'm not wasting memory on an array - I'm just tracking the two largest positives and the two smallest negatives.

Comment: thanks for all the help! I've finally made it work :). I still needed to add some if commands so that the code works if n is less than 4, still if not your suggestion I probably wouldn't have came up with a solution.